# Moving implicitly typed variables to object initialiser

Tags: c#, types, casting

How can I modify the following code:

```
var people = new[] {
   new { name = "John", surname = "Smith" },
   new { name = "John", surname = "Doe" },
};
```

To not use the `var` keyword (so I can initialise the variable in an object initialiser) and still be able to access the elements like this?:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(people[0].surname); //John
System.Console.WriteLine(people[1].surname); //Doe
```

Comment: You can *already* access `people[0].surname` that way. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve which isn't already fine... Or are you talking about a *field* initializer? (It's important to get the terminology right here.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I want the variable `people` to be a public object property.

Comment: Then you either need to use dynamic typing, or create a named type exposing those properties. Anonymous types simply aren't designed to be exposed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

and then have a [`collection of this model`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(new Person { Name = "John", Surname = "Smith" });
people.Add(new Person { Name = "John", Surname = "Doe" });
```

or:

```
var people = new List<Person> 
{ 
    new Person { Name = "John", Surname = "Smith" }, 
    new Person { Name = "John", Surname = "Doe" } 
};
```

and then you can still:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(people[0].Surname); //John
System.Console.WriteLine(people[1].Surname); //Doe
```

Comment: Good point, I will probably do it that way. However are you sure there isn't an easier way to initialise the same object as by using the var keyword?

Comment: Sure, you could use the `var` keyword if you want: `var people = new List<Person>();`, or you could even do it as a one-liner if you prefer: `var people = new List<Person> { new Person { Name = "John", Surname = "Smith" }, new Person { Name = "John", Surname = "Doe" } };`.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot; you will have to define a proper class for these objects or reuse one (e.g. `Tuple`).

Technically the one-word change from `var` to `dynamic` will also do the trick, but of course this changes the essence of the member dramatically so it's not equivalent by any stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need to create a named type for that data:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Then use that type when creating the array:

```
People[] people;

//...

people = new People[]{
    new Person{ Name = "John", Surname = "Smith" },
    new Person{ Name = "John", Surname = "Doe" },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'dynamic'

```
dynamic people = new[] {
   new { name = "John", surname = "Smith" },
   new { name = "John", surname = "Doe" },
};
```

And then call it

```
Console.WriteLine(people[0].name);
```

Note - Works on framework 4.0 onwards, also comes with the caveats mentioned already.